# Angular 2 project in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I want to create a single page application using `Angular 2` + `Asp.Net Core` API. I would like to use `angular cli` for angular application, and I will use Visual Studio as development environment. But I am not sure how should I organize things.
Should I have:

1. One .Net Core project with angular files copied to wwwroot
2. Two .Net Core projects, one for API, second one for angular where angular
   files are copied to wwwroot
3. One .Net Core for API and Web Site project for angular.

What is the best way for doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Channel 9](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Visual-Studio-2017-Launch/WEB-103) has a tutorial for doing that.

There are different templates you can download.
 I use this one.
[image: 1]

After that, you can create the new project from it.
 See the image below.
[image: 2]

By the [document,](https://angular.io/guide/visual-studio-2015)You might replace to replace web.config file Webserver section with the code if you use IIS.

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/src/" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Or you can follow [this tutorial.](https://medium.com/@levifuller/building-an-angular-application-with-asp-net-core-in-visual-studio-2017-visualized-f4b163830eaa)